# System.Timers.Timer Not Triggered On Time in CPU-Intensive Program

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have .Net framwork 4.7.2 application, which handles cpu-intensive workload.
It uses system.timers.timer, intend to force program timeout after x mins.
The timer sometimes is not able to trigger on time.

Any suggestion on making the timer work properly, without loosing workload efficiency?

Following is the code to demonstrate the issue.
The timer set to triggered every 5 secs, but result is not as expected, which is shown in screenshot.
Please note that size of taskCollection is not predictable.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var taskCollection = new string[new Random().Next(10, 100)];
            SetupTimer();
            Parallel.ForEach(taskCollection
                , new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 }
                , task =>
                {
                    SlowTask();
                }
            );
        }

        static void SetupTimer()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += (s_, e_) =>
            {
                OnTimedEvent(s_, e_);
            };
            aTimer.Interval = 5000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine($"Timer has been started at {DateTime.Now}.");
        }

        static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Timer has been triggered at {DateTime.Now}.");
        }

        static void SlowTask()
        {
            long nthPrime = FindPrimeNumber(10000000); //set higher value for more time
        }

        static long FindPrimeNumber(int n)
        {
            int count = 0;
            long a = 2;
            while (count < n)
            {
                long b = 2;
                int prime = 1;
                while (b * b <= a)
                {
                    if (a % b == 0)
                    {
                        prime = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    b++;
                }
                if (prime > 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                a++;
            }
            return (--a);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: start the timer on a separate thread, and not use main... and then see if u get the expected behavior, mmm no wait last i remember is it already is internally, odd

Comment: The Timer is only guaranteed to be __no faster__ than the Interval.

Comment: @Seabizkit, I think System.Timers.Timer internally started in different thread.
Doesn't hurt to give it a try.
I tried Task.Run(()=>{ StartTimer();} ), the issue is still there.

Comment: try changing ur MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 1 then 2 and see if you get the expected behavior, not sure what -1 is meant to be, if that is unlimited OS max then thats probably a bad idea

Comment: @user3191941 move the timer out of the static and put it as a var on main, and see if thats it, it may be sumthing funcky with scope.

Comment: @Seabizkit, if I change MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a small number, the timer will honor the interval. However, the size of my workload is not predictable, that's why I put -1 there to let .Net framework to provide "best" efficiency by its own. Some people suggest use logical processor size as MaxDegreeOfParallelism for CPU intensive workload. Maybe that's one option.

Comment: @TaW Interesting. What technology do you recommend for timeout purpose?

Comment: @user3191941 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_MaxDegreeOfParallelism, my guess would be that you are cpu staved... aka you are not giving parts of the process/program enough cpu time to actually keep count correctly. first move it out of the static,  or at least make sure its life span is guaranteed.., you could put in a non static class so its scope is the same as the main. then make the MaxDegreeOfParallelism 1 less than core count and see what happens.

Comment: I would say that doing Prime calcs is not a valid usage for normal usage... also across max cores.. is like saying do nothing but crunch numbers, not really for cpu, if you need to crunch Primes then this should be somehow off loaded to gpu, i suspect that the Primes was just to simulate work... but i think this is a non realistic way to simulate.

Comment: @Seabizkit I have moved StartTimer code into main, it behaves same.

Comment: Try to add the Timer events to, say, a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, DateTime>` (easier to order) instead of printing to the Console and set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to the number of Cores -1. Then print the contents of the Dictionary after you have stopped the Timer, when the parallel procedure completes

Comment: This is almost certainly thread-pool starvation, because both `Parallel` and `Timer` use the thread-pool. Turning down the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` makes a lot of sense

Comment: @Seabizkit I over estimated benefits of MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1.  
When I change to  MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, the timer started working properly. And performance is even better when running test app on my local.  
Both setting makes CPU hitting 100%, I don't know why timer doesn't work properly when use -1.  I guess over spinning threads for CPU-bound workload cause overhead and problem.
Please put your solution in answer section, I'd like to mark it as answer.

Comment: @Charlieface Initially I thought this is thread-pool starvation, until I found thread-pool has 32767 worker threads available. I was hesitate reducing MaxDegreeOfParallelism, because set it to  `ProcessorCount - 1` would means 50% cost of 2 vCPU VM kind of getting wasted. We use thousands of small instances in cloud for our CPU-intensive workload.